# Google Maps API in Android--using a proxy server

Tags: android, google-maps, proxy

I am trying to develop a simple app using Google maps.
While running the app i can see only the grid and the map controls.
I did obtain an API key and included it into main.xml file.
The permissions for the internet was also granted in the androidmanifest.xml.
My browser in avd is connecting to internet and when i run the native map app in the avd, it shows the following error.

****Network Failure**  ...  **Wrong remote strings version.GMM Server must be hosting:/strings_remote_533149424.dat******

### GoogleMapActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }
}
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0kuSQz9hsxal-_JpKGJbFp__zLqhl5d4gG3ohDg"
/>
```

### manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.googlemap"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />


   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity android:name=".GoogleMapActivity" 
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
      </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     </application>

      </manifest>
```

I'm using a proxy to connect to the internet.
Can anyone plz help me out with this..plz help me!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about GoogleMaps, there are no indications in manuals if the proxy could matter in displaying maps. If you got the map controls and the GoogleMap grid, this means that you have been connected to the map server but map tiles permissions were denied to you. What to do:
1. Check it if you got the DEBUG key or the Release key
2. Use the Debug key if you are testing locally with the "apk" downloaded from your PC
3. Use the Release key if you are debugging your "apk" downloaded from the Android market
It looks like you are stumbling upon one of the upper bottle-necks.

If these indications did not work, show your settings and source code on this forum for others to react appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set this permision in manifest: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and in aplication  ???

Answer (score 0):

I revisited your question and found 2 possible flaws.

1. Rewrite your manifest file as follows. USES-PERMISSION tags should be out of the APPLICATION tags.
2. Possibly, you may have been using a wrong debug-key. Please, generate an new debug-key according to manuals to use with this application on development PC.
3. If the problem persists, please update your development environment to the latest and test again.

Your rewritten manifest.xml should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.googlemap"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
   <activity android:name=".GoogleMapActivity" 
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
      </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     </application>

      </manifest>
```